# How to add (add,edit,delete) buttons in GXT3 grid

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

There are a way to add (add,edit,delete) buttons in GXT 3 grid inside a panel! 
i have 3 Anchors (3 a hrefs > add - edit - delete ) inside VerticalPanel, can i add this vertical panel as cell in my GXT3 Grid ?
if that is complicated or not possible, which is the normal and easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid example, it uses the GWT cell pattern (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html). You can use whatever you want in a cell...

Comment: whatever you want in a cell! i don't think so, because already tried and it's really complicated, specially when adding many buttons or anchors in same cell, anyway tanks..